# not ordinary string replace issue

Tags: c#, string, replace, concatenation

In C# I have a variable:

```
string text = "some nice text #ttt#";
```

now I want to replace #ttt# with concatenation of 3 strings;

```
string str1 = "\'%";
textbox1.Text = "AAA";
string str2 = "%\'";
```

so I do:

```
//it returns: "some nice text '%%'"
string text = String.Replace("#ttt#", String.Concat(str1, textbox1.Text, str2));

//it returns: "some nice text '%%'"
string text = String.Replace("#ttt#", (str1+textbox1.Text+str2));
```

If I snipe `String.Concat(str1, textbox1.Text, str2)` in debuger it shows correct `"some nice text '%AAA%'"`

Any ideas how to replace it so between %% will be `textbox1.Text` string?

Comment: I know regular expressions. Its an idea to use it but its not the answer to my question why its not replacing correctly.

Comment: `String.Replace("#ttt#",...` should not even compile - can you please provide actual sample?

Comment: What you posted wouldn't compile, please show your real code.

Answer (score 2):

You're not replacing the text:

```
string text = "some nice text #ttt#";
string str1 = "\'%";
string xxx = "AAA";
string str2 = "%\'";
string result = text.Replace("#ttt#", String.Concat(str1, 
xxx, str2));
```

Result is now "some nice text '%AAA%'"